# Display Div on top of Kendo Grid

Tags: css, angular, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid to display Grid view of data. I have a column with button that, when clicked, shows a list of options on top of the page and left to the button.

I am not using Kendo Popup or context menu, but just using ng-template with structural directive logic.

What i look for?

[image]

What i get?

[image]

This is my Kendo grid column:

```
<div style="position: relative">
  <kendo-grid>
  ...
    <kendo-grid-column title="SAMPLE">
     <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
       <div class="context-dropdown-menu" *ngIf="showIndex === rowIndex && showDialog" style="position: absolute;">
         <ul>
           <li> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Item2.1 </li>
           <li> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Item2.2 </li>
           <li> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Item2.3 </li>
         </ul>
       <div>
       <button type="button" (click)="clicked(rowIndex)"> Click </button>
      </ng-template>
   </kendo-grid-column>
...
  </kendo-grid>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can add `z-index: 999999` CSS property to sample click... dropdown to show over the dnedo grid

Comment: Yeah i did that, and no change.

Comment: its purely CSS issue if we can have an example demo on stackblitz etc then I can have better idea.

Comment: Please refer. I've added sample try here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pfcqge

Comment: I have updated your stackblitz example its fixed now you can check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below style in your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pfcqge) example it will work fine.

```
.context-dropdown-menu {
  margin: 0 -10.75rem;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 170px;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.context-dropdown-menu ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  background: #e4e4e4
 }

.context-dropdown-menu ul li {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  color: #617189;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.context-dropdown-menu ul li:hover {
  background: #f5f5f5;
 }
```

Comment: This was exactly what i needed. Thanks a ton :)